# Retrieving Excel File via WebClient POST

Tags: .net, excel, webclient

I'm trying to post some data to an API which returns an Excel file, and I'm able to successfully use `UploadString`, but I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error on the `UploadData` call. The string returned from the `UploadString` call is partly readable, but there's some funky characters / formatting in the file / variable. I took a look at the `Download` methods on the `WebClient`, but none of them seem to have a parameter to accept the post body data I need to include. I have no trouble via Postman getting the file. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Dim client As New Net.WebClient
Using client
        Dim cookie As String = "myCookie"
        Dim contentType As String = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Dim postData As String = "contentThatNeedsPosted"
        Dim postURL As String = "www.myposturl.com"
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie)
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, contentType)

        Dim response1 = client.UploadString(postUrl, postData)
        Dim response = client.UploadData(postUrl, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData))

        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\myfile.xls", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response1))
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`client.UploadData(postUrl, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData)`

Comment: Thanks... I tried this before but it wasn't working... but it was a silly mistake.. making the back to back calls when I was testing made it not work, taking out response1 or response makes the other work